# Wildcards in aptitude

Tags: aptitude

I want to do something like

```
aptitude -P install mypackage*
```

which should install all packages which start with "mypackage". How can I do this with `aptitude`?

Comment: I don't have the time to write up a proper answer right now, but you may find [Searching for strings](http://www.algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s01.html) helpful.

Comment: The `*` wildcard is a function of the shell, not of aptitude. You can configure your shell to expand the package list.

Comment: Try ~n to get that functionality.

Answer (score 8):

```
aptitude install '~n ^mypackage'
```

With multi-arch, you probably want to limit it to one architecture:

```
aptitude install '~n ^mypackage (~r amd64 | ~r all)'
```

Comment: how would that work if you wanted to apply to two rules, ex: `aptitude install pack* mypack*` ?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira, it's an extended regular expression, so `aptitude install '~n "^(my)?pack"'` or `aptitude install '~n "^(pack|mypack)"'` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
aptitude search '^mypackage' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs aptitude install
```